# Mark Diagnosis with a certain ICD-10 Code as main diagnosis

Tags: uima, ruta

I would like to mark all diagnoses whose conceptId starts with "G35." as main diagnosis. How can I implement this?

```
d:Diagnosis{d.conceptId.startswith("G35.") -> MainDiagnosis}; 
d:Diagnosis{d.conceptId[0:3] == "G35." -> MainDiagnosis};
```

All the best
Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP` condition to match a pattern on the value of a feature (i.e. Diagnosis.conceptId).
A solution in your case would be something like this:

```
d:Diagnosis{REGEXP(d.conceptId, "^G35.*") -> MainDiagnosis};
```

For more information on `REGEXP` Condition, feel free to consult the [documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.conditions.regexp)

---

Another option would be to use StringFunctions; similar to what you tried to do in the first rule.

```
d:Diagnosis{startsWith(d.conceptId, "G35") -> MainDiagnosis};
```

However this requires you to activate an optional extension `org.apache.uima.ruta.string.bool.BooleanOperationsExtension` in your Ruta Analysis Engine by setting its parameter PARAM_ADDITIONAL_EXTENSIONS